# If Data in Column appears within Date Range then highlight

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I would like to do some conditional formatting on a Project Planner that will highlight a persons name if the dates selected for an activity to which they are assigned fall within a date range for another action to which they are also assigned.

On my spreadsheet I have the following columns:

- Column A: Activity
- Column B: Start Date
- Column C: End Date
- Column D:    Responsible    Person

To give an example of how I would like the formula to work:

Person A has been assigned an activity that begins on 01/02/14 and ends on 07/02/14.  If a subsequent activity is then added to the sheet that either begins or ends on any of the dates within the range 01/02/14-07/02/14 and the person is assigned to it, i would like to use conditional formatting to highlight the cell as a sign to the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Do you have anything yet?

Comment: Hi Jerry,I've been wrestling with formulas and the best i can come up with is an IF function with nested AND/OR functions, but it isn't working for me at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe use `COUNTIFS` with the conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,D1,B:B,"<="&C1,C:C,">="&B1)>1
```

This counts all the instances where the following conditions are satisfied:

1. The responsible person is the same person (`D:D, D1` part)
2. The dates the other activities begin are before or equal to the date a certain activity ends. (`B:B,"<="&C1` part)
3. The dates the other activities end are equal or after to the date a certain activity begins. (`C:C,">="&B1` part)

The formula can make Excel respond quite slowly since it takes into consideration the whole column. Change it to a range if possible, for example, if you always have about 100 activities, you could maybe use:

```
=COUNTIFS(D1:D120,D1,B1:B120,"<="&C1,C1:C120,">="&B1)>1
```

Here is what I get after using this conditional formatting:

[image]

`COUNTIFS` returns a number; a count of cells that satisfies the conditions. Since we have `>1` at the end, this means that the cell(s) will get highlighted if there is more than one cell with the same conditions.

Comment: Hi Jerry,I think this is exactly what I was looking for, I've got a couple of kinks I'm working through with it, but it seems to do the job perfectly, and is much more elgant than anything I was coming up with!

Comment: @user3240379 You're welcome! Oh, I forgot to mention something about how this works. `COUNTIFS` returns a number; a count of cells that satisfies the conditions. Since we have `>1` at the end, this means that the cell will get highlighted if there is more than one cell with the same conditions.